# Can Google Earth export kml files usable in the Google Earth Api?

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible for me to go through and edit my virtual copy of the landscape being worked on and export that to kml, usable in the Google Earth API? In other words if I have my models, and color markings laid over the earth, can I share those certain addons through GE API (not allowing users to edit it).

Comment: This is referring to Google Earth Pro

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There are a couple ways to do it.

In the left panel, right-click on the feature or features you want to capture in KML and select Copy.  Then open your favorite editor and paste.  You'll get the KML.  You can save the KML to a file.

Another choice is to right-click on the feature and click "Save Place As...", which will let you save the file as a KML or KMZ.

Google hosts a [tutorial](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/kmz.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but you will have to create an GE API instance.
We are coming up with a new product that will handle that.
Send me a note to jdelcid@3delcid.com if you are interested in knowing more about it and perhaps using it for your projects.
Best.
Jorge.